# Double: using the actual number of decimal places

Tags: c++

I'm creating a calculator program, but I don't know how to set the precision of the decimal places of the calculated answer so that the actual number of decimal places is displayed.
Examples:
-If the answer is 6, it would display 6, not 6.0000000

-if the answer is 8.23, it would display 8.23, not 8.23000000

etc.

How would I set the precision as such?

Comment: How are you displaying the numbers? What documentation are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, use the method precision to set the number of needed placeholders, like:

```
 double f = 3.14159;
  std::cout.unsetf ( std::ios::floatfield );                // floatfield not set
  std::cout.precision(5); //will output 5 digits after point
  std::cout << f << '\n';
  std::cout.precision(10); //will output 10 digits after point, like 3.1415900000
  std::cout << f << '\n';
  std::cout.setf( std::ios::fixed, std:: ios::floatfield ); // floatfield set to fixed
  std::cout << f << '\n';
```

To remove any trailing zeroes, you can use

```
std::cout.precision(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can set:

```
std::cout.precision(6); // 6 digits
```

or whatever value you need. Or:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << my_double_value << std::endl;
```

Comment: As far as I understand his question he doesn't want any trailing zeros. So it's not just a precision matter.

Comment: @Layne std::setprecision doesn't display trailing zeros.

Comment: Anyway, the answer doesn't make sense as OP said he 'accidentally tagged this as C++.'

Comment: @NikosC. Wow. I actually didn't know that. But you could by accident cut off a digit which is not zero.

Comment: @Layne. Often you have to, consider `double f = 1.0/3.0`

Answer (score 1):

`iostream` provides a `setprecision` function:

```
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n'
```

Output will be:

```
3.1416
3.14159
3.14159
3.141590000
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
printf("%g",value);
```

Answer (score 1):

There *isn't* an "actual number of decimal places". Double precision has a number of *binary* places but these don't map reliably into a number of decimal places. An easy example is `1.0/10,0` which should be 0.1 but is actually a number quite close to 0.1; how many decimal places you show for sums such as these is thus not a quality of the double itself but rather of how many decimal places you want to show.

How you can truncate to the number you want has been discussed in the other answers.